# Looking for a book in which one of the main characters has powers and it is post apocalyptic

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

From what I remember, there's a big scene in the book where two teenagers are fighting. The two main characters were away from people, hiding in the woods in a tent. They have a car with a broken spark plug. The girl has powers. She can go invisible (somewhat) and do some other things but she ends up breaking the car's spark plug because she was angry (I think?).

I read it about 3-4 years ago (2014-2015). It was in English and it did not seem super old.

Comment: When did you read it? How old did it seem then? What language was it in? As of right now, there's not enough information to go with.

Comment: What does "Out in hiding" mean?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd Not that there is anything wrong with additional info - but I feel like, if a story you've read matches this, it's probably the same story.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I wondered that as well

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd by "Out in hiding" I mean that the two main characters were away from people. Hiding in the woods and they had a tent. It was in English and it did not seem super old. Read about 3/4 years ago.

Comment: @N.Juneau Okay. Can you add those details to your question, and anything else you can remember?

Comment: Did the story blurb by any chance use the word "sweatrooms"? or the phrase "You've got to come and work for us"?

Answer (score 2):

This could be the [Influence series](https://books.google.com/books/about/Influence.html?id=pQBBvgAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description) by David Bernstein.
[image: Influence]

It’s dystopian post-apocalyptic teen angst Hunger Games knockoff with the lead being Kaylin, an *influencer*.

Influencers can “push” peoples’ minds, altering their perception of reality, make things invisible, or control minds.

Common elements:
Published about 2016.
Teens.
Teens fighting.
The girl has powers.
She can go invisible (somewhat) and do some other things.
Post-apocalyptic.
Post-apocalyptic *woods*